# Background is too zoomed in

Tags: html, css

I have a background image for my hero section. On some screen, the background image fits perfectly. However, on some other screens such as my iPhone, it's really way too zoomed in.

I tried solutions on Stack Overflow, such as `background-size:contain` or `background-size:100%`, but I end up with like a background that it is repeated 3-4 times. Here is my code for the background:

```css
.bg-hero {
    background-image: url('/img/background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

[image: Example of current situation]

Comment: consider different images and use the media queries to load the correct one.

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you give more precisions on what the other image would have to have different?

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet so we can see the problem happening? Thanks. Incidentally, you can stop background-images repeating-repeat  with the background-size: no-repeat no-repeat, but that doesn't seem to be your problem here.

Comment: I've tried lots of aspect ratios/sizes and I cannot reproduce your problem. In each case the image is correctly centered and it's cropped either at the sides or at the top/bottom as needed to satisfy the 'cover' requirement. Are you sure that the image is being cropped both at the top/bottom AND at the sides (i.e. zoomed) at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** the initial answer raised the question of background-attachment: fixed which can cause problems in some combinations of settings. However, in this case testing with different aspect ratios images and leaving the fixed in I was unable to recreate the problem, the background-size: cover worked in both orientations. I leave the info below here for now in case it helps point to something that is causing the problem.

**Original:**

The problem may be in these settings:

```
.bg-hero {
    background-image: url('/img/background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

background-attachment: fixed is not supported in IOS. Depending on what version it can lead to e.g. overstretched image (though this question talks of zooming in rather than stretching). See https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attachment but the background-size: cover should have got round that for you.

> Partial support refers to supporting local but not fixed

Comment: I don't think it's happening because of `background-attachment` property. It has got to be because of the orientation of the image being used.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of the image you are using for the background are not appropriate for mobile screens. The image you are using has landscape orientation. There are two things you can do :

1. Use different image having portrait orientation. And add media query in your CSS code.

2. This approach might not be suitable but you can give it a try. Instead of using image as background, use a relevant color for background (like some shade of brown in this case), and add image as a separate element in your HTML. You can again manage the size of image using media queries. And make sure you `position` image element as `fixed`.

Comment: The problem can occur for me on an iPad which has aspect ratio very similar to my laptop so I'd be surprised if it was aspect ratio. Have you seen the problem?

Comment: Hi, I haven't attached an image. I've given a link to the caniuse.com site which says that IOS does not support background-attachment fixed.

Comment: @AHaworth Sorry, I mistook you for the question poster. The dimension are of course similar to that of a laptop, but the orientations of both devices are different. Laptop has landscape orientation, whereas iPads along with other mobile devices have portrait orientations.

Answer (score 0):

Try min-height and check one

```
.bg-hero {
        background-image: url('/img/background.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        min-height:100vh;
    }
```